# Tomcat JNDI datasource connecting to wrong database with similar name

Tags: java, sql-server, tomcat, jndi, tomcat8

I'm developing a Web Application using Apache Tomcat 8 and SQL Server 2005.

I had to "duplicate" my databse to create a parallel Q&A environment running on the same server. I made a database backup and created a new database using said backup with a slightly different name; The name of the original db is "**TSIM**" and the name of the second db is "**TSIMQA**" although they are identical internally.

The problem started when I tried to connect to "**TSIMQA**" changing a the *databaseName* resource in my project's **context.xml** file from:

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/TSIMQA">
<Resource
  auth="Container" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
  maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="5000" name="connpool"
  type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=TSIM;user=***;password=***"/></Context>
```

to:

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/TSIMQA">
<Resource
  auth="Container" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
  maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="5000" name="connpool"
  type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=TSIMQA;user=***;password=***"/></Context>
```

here's the java class where I'm getting the connection:

```
public static Connection getConnection(){
    try{
        Context initContext;
        initContext = new InitialContext();
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env/connpool");
        return ds.getConnection();
    }catch(NamingException | SQLException e){
        Logger.getLogger(DBConn.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

It connects and seems like everything is ok but it is in fact still connecting to "**TSIM**".

What I'have tried is restarting Tomcat, recompiling and re-uploading the war again, changing the qa database name but it keeps connecting to the original one.

I know it its unsing the information provided in the context.xml file because when I remove the user or the password I get an exception from the connection.

I've tried to change the database name to "**QATSIM**" hoping to get some clue of what's going on but it behaves the same way.

I'm using Netbeans to build the app by the way. (I haven't done the set up of any database so i don't think it is trying to specify any default datasource replacing the one in the context.xml file).

Thank you very much for your time and forgive my limitted english.

Comment: I have a feeling context.XML is just for netbeans (it is for context related stuff), if you delete this file from webapps does it still connect? Edit, delete and run outside of netbeans

Comment: It should work as it is. Since it does not must be a configuration issue. So it seems you already upload the war file manually tomcat. Go to tomcat/webapps dir and inside your app check the webapps\yourapp\META-INFcontext.xml has the right value (maybe your context.xml was cached by the netbeans and the update is not included in the war). If the context is the right one. Go to tomcat work and delete its content. If it doesnt help check if you dont have global resources defined in your tomcat server.xml